# C# System.Drawing, не получается нарисовать изображение, форма не реагирует

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал WinForms форму, не получается нарисовать изображение (после запуска форма пуста).
До этого получилось, но после того как я добавил и затем убрал BackgroundImage у формы, код перестал работать.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GameProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = CreateGraphics();
        }

        Graphics g;

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g.DrawImage(Resource1.Untitled, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

В чем ошибка? После запуска форма пуста. Причем в последствии, если подвигать форму или открыть ее, то изображение появляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте, назначен ли метод `Form1_Paint` обработчиком события формы `Paint`.

Comment: Да, назначен ```this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);```

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, выявилась интересная деталь. Если после запуска подвинуть форму к левому верхнему углу экрана, или открыть полностью, изображение появляется.

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawImage`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! А почему не работало через g.DrawImage() при запуске? Ведь через таймер или по нажатию кнопки срабатывало. Это проблема с WinForms или моя ошибка?

Comment: Я просто показал, как обычно делают.